# How to add a SSL postgres connection using CLI for Cloud Composer?

Tags: postgresql, ssl, connection, gcloud, google-cloud-composer

using airflow locally, I was able to add a SSL Postgres connection using this :

```
./airflow.sh connections add connection_name --conn-uri 'postgres://user:@host:port/db?sslmode=verify-ca&sslcert=<>.crt&sslca=<>.crt&sslkey=<>.key.pk8'
```

Now I'm using Cloud Composer, and I want to add this connection again, but I can't find how. I tried using gcloud CLI as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections#gcloud_2) but I can't find the right method or the right arguments to use.

Does anyone know how to do it ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Easiest way to configure PostgreSQL connection is by using the Airflow Webserver console and navigating to  Admin > Connection > Create. [refer](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/stable/connections/postgres.html)

Comment: For [CLI](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/accessing/airflow-cli#running-commands) could you try the following command  :
 `gcloud composer environments run \
  ENVIRONMENT_NAME \
-- location LOCATION \
  connections -- --add \
-- conn_id=CONNECTION_ID \
  --conn-uri 'postgresql://user:@host:port/db?sslmode=verify-ca&sslcert=<>.crt&sslca=<>.crt&sslkey=<>.key.pk8' `

Comment: @SakshiGatyan
I tried this like [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections#creating_a_connection_to_another_project) both with airflow 1.* and 2.* since the command changes a little, but I keep having the error :
`(gcloud.beta.composer.environments.run) unrecognized arguments:
  
dt_test

  --conn-uri (did you mean '--configuration'?)
`
or something similar : every arguments after the `--` are unrecognized.

Comment: Okay I found the issue : windows. For some reason, that command doesn't seem to work using the CLI on windows, but I tried on linux and it worked fine.

Comment: @SakshiGatyan Yeah i tried but I need more reputation to upvote your awnser... it tells me :
Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion in comments, you can configure PostgreSQL connection in Cloud Composer using :

**CLI (Linux)**

Cloud SDK supports Airflow CLI [subcommand](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer/environments/run#SUBCOMMAND) to run. When specifying the connection as URI, extras (ie. sslmode,sslcert etc) are passed as parameters of the URI.

For example refer the following command:

```
gcloud composer environments run \
  ENVIRONMENT_NAME \
  --location LOCATION \
  connections -- --add \
  --conn_id=CONNECTION_ID \
  --conn-uri 'postgresql://postgres_user:XXXXXXXXXXXX@1.1.1.1:5432/postgresdb?sslmode=verify-ca&sslcert=%2Ftmp%2Fclient-cert.pem&sslkey=%2Ftmp%2Fclient-key.pem&sslrootcert=%2Ftmp%2Fserver-ca.pem'
```

For more information refer to [this](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#add) Airflow Documentation.

**Cloud Composer Airflow Console**

- In the Airflow webserver console generated by Cloud Composer,
  navigate to Admin > Connection > Create
- Specify Connection Id,Connection Type (Postgres)
- Fill the required parameters ie. Host,Login, Password. ([Refer](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/stable/connections/postgres.html))
- Extra: extra parameters (as json) ie.sslmode,sslcert, sslca, sslkey